# Angular Form does not submit on enter when not focused

Tags: angular, forms

I have some Angular 6 forms and I focus on the first available field. They contain a submit button and when I press enter, the form is submitted automatically and the ngSubmit event is triggered.

There is one particular form which only contains a radio group, and I am not focusing on any field. In this case, ngSubmit is not triggered.

If I click on a radio button and then press enter, the form submits correctly.

Is there any way of making the form submit on enter even if none of the fields within the form are focused? Should I focus on the form itself somehow?

Form:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-radio-group [formControl]="control" name="test">
        <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.key">
        {{option.value}}
        </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Stackblitz:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arcwjv?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Try to add the `type=submit` to the button.

Comment: In my specific use case of editing inline with a Kendo grid, I found that my Kendo grid was missing the ```[navigable]=true``` flag, which prevented the enter key from being used for form submit. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Always specify the type attribute for the  element. Different browsers may use different default types for the  element.

submit = The button is a submit button (submits form-data)

```
<button type="submit" >Submit</button>
```

Comment: Adding type=submit doesn't make a difference. I am pretty sure the problem is that the form is not focused. If I click on a radio button and then press enter, it does work.

Comment: can you create a stackbliz? so I can assist you better

Comment: This saved my life!

Comment: Thanks, I've created a Stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arcwjv?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score -1):

Add the type `submit` to the button.

```
<button type="submit" >Submit</button>
```

Comment: This does not solve anything. Also why should I use the submit event? I am already using the ngSubmit event. This is not the problem either

Comment: `(submit)="onSubmit()"` is not necessary to submit a form. https://angular.io/guide/forms